# Show API Data in a View without ID

Tags: ios, swift, api, swiftui

I have a small weather project and I got stuck in the phase where I have to show the results from the API in a view. The API is from WeatherAPI.
I mention that the JSON file doesn't have an id and I receive the results in Console.
What is the best approach for me to solve this problem?
Thank you for your help!

This is the APIService.

```
import Foundation

class APIService: ObservableObject {

    func apiCall(searchedCity: String) {
     let apikey = "secret"
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=\(apikey)&q=\(searchedCity)&aqi=no") else {
        return
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            return
        }
        do {
            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherModel.self, from: data)
            
            print(response)
            print("SUCCESS")
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    }
}
```

This is the ForecastModel

```
import Foundation

struct WeatherModel: Codable {
    var location: Location
    var current: Current
}

struct Location: Codable {
    var name: String
}
struct Current: Codable, {
    var temp_c: Decimal
    var wind_kph: Decimal
}
```

Here is the view where I want to call.

```
import SwiftUI

struct WeatherView: View {
    
  
    @StateObject var callApi = APIService()
    @Binding var searchedCity: String

    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Color.backgroundColor.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all)
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 50) {
                    
                comparation
                temperature
                clothes
                Spacer()
                
                }
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    self.callApi.apiCall(searchedCity: "\(searchedCity)")
                })
                
            }
            
        }
                
    }
}

struct WeatherView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var searchedCity: String = ""
    static var previews: some View {
        WeatherView(searchedCity: $searchedCity)
    }
}

fileprivate extension WeatherView {
    
    var comparation: some View {
        
        Text("Today is  ")
            .fontWeight(.medium)
    }
    
    var temperature: some View {
        Text("It is ?C with ? and ? winds")
            .fontWeight(.medium)
    }
    
    var clothes: some View {
        Text("Wear a ?")
            .fontWeight(.medium)
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a `@Published` property in ApiService that holds the downloaded data. Why do you need an Id?

Comment: In the cases that I saw, the model would conform to Identifiable (so the model you'd have an ID). In APIService, the completion handler would be an Array with the results that are called in a view, so I thought that I need an ID to show the results in a view, in my case.
Could you explain me more with the `@Published` property, how can I use it in APIService? 
Thank you!

Comment: It looks to me like you are only downloading one item at a time so I don't see any array and your view is only displaying one item. That being said, you can still make your type conform to Identifiable even if the api type doesn't contain an id if you know one property that is unique. I am not going to explain `@Published` to you since that kind of knowledge is basic SwiftUI stuff that you should acquire yourself.

Comment: Yes, I know about `@Published`. The idea was to apply it in the API and I have now some ideas.
Thank you!